# How to retrieve value from the Check boxes?

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm trying to get the emails corresponding to the checkbox using the following codes. But, I'm not getting the correct checked emails in the new variable. Can anyone please check ??

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE username='$username'");
$num=mysql_num_rows($query);
$info=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$i=0;
$msg='';
?>
  <table width="672" border="0">
<?php 
$i=0;
while($info)
{
?>
<form action="compose.php" method="post">
<tr style="font-size:14px;">
    <td width="21" bgcolor="#f2f2f2"> <input type="checkbox" name="add" onSelect="<?php $msg=$msg.$info['email'].", ";?>"/> </td>
    <td width="229" bgcolor="#f2f2f2"> <?php  echo $info['email']; ?> </td>
    <td width="408" bgcolor="#f2f2f2"> <?php  echo $info['name']; ?> </td>
  </tr>
<?php 
$info=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$i++;
}

$_SESSION['contacts']=$msg;
?>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td><br />
<input class="new-button" type="submit" value="Insert & Compose" name="submit" /></td>
</tr>
</form>



</table>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused with the: `onSelect="<?php $msg=$msg.$info['email'].", ";?>"` part. You first need to POST the form before you can get the value.

Comment: It appears you are confusing client-side JavaScript with server-side PHP. PHP produces HTML which is sent to the browser. JavaScript (such as an onSelect function) is executed by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

To get any value back for checkboxes they must have a `value=`. In your case you probably would want the value to be the according email address.

One problem with your code is using `onSelect=` instead of `value=`, and second you didn't print the actual value into the page. Rewrite it to:

```
<td width="21" bgcolor="#f2f2f2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="add"
     value="<?php print $info['email']; ?>"/> </td>
```

If you need the `$msg` variable to do something, assemble it after the output.

Comment: could you tell me how to get the values corresponding to the checked boxes in the $msg variable ??

Comment: I'm not sure why you want it in the $_SESSION. Usually you would receive the values in `$_POST["add"]`. Now that I think of it, you probably want **all** values to show up there. That's why you need to adapt the `<input name="add[]" ` (notice the `[]` after the `add` name). Then `$msg = $_POST["add"]` becomes an array after the submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="add" value="<?php echo $msg.$info['email'];?>"/>
```

checkbox does not have onSelect event probobly you got value in mind and in PHP code you should `echo` and what `.", "` is for?